# Initialize backbone model using its child model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have following backbone models

```
var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        name: ''
    }
});

var Child = Parent.extend({
    defaults: {
        color: '',
        shape: '',
        isValid: false
});
```

Now I have the following object of "Child" model

```
var child = new Child({
    id: '101',
    name: 'Abc',
    color: 'White',
    shape: 'Square',
    isValid: true
});
```

I need to create a "Parent" model object using this "Child" model object for which I did the following:

```
var json = convertToJSON(child);
var parent = new Parent(json);
```

But here the attributes of "Child" model are also filled into parent object of "Parent" model. Is there any way to fill only those attributes applicable to the "Parent" model in this new object? I don't want to use "delete" to remove inapplicable attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick), proxied onto your child object as [`child.pick`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-Underscore-Methods) to pick specific attributes,
2. You can extract the keys of `Parent.defaults` to determine what you need

This translates into :

```
var parent = new Parent(
    child.pick(_.keys(Parent.prototype.defaults))
);
```

And a demo https://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/u5rfpa6v/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `pick` method on a child model to get only required attributes

```
var json = child.pick('color', 'shape');
var parent = new Parent(json);
```

It will return an object that you can pass to a parent model.
You can read more about it [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-Underscore-Methods)

Alternatively you can use [es2015 destructive assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) but you would need [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) transpiler for it.

```
const {color, shape} = child;
const parent = new Parent({color, shape});
```